# Django static files redirecting to URL with language code

Tags: django, mezzanine, django-modeltranslation

I'm using `Mezzanine 4.1.0` with `Django 1.9.12` and `django-modeltranslation 0.1.2`.

All of my static files are getting redirected as if they were pages:

```
"GET /static/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/2.0" 301 0
"GET /static/js/bootstrap.js/ HTTP/2.0" 302 0
"GET /en/static/js/bootstrap.js/ HTTP/2.0" 404 6960
```

Has anyone seen this before?  It only just started happening, for no apparent reason.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  It only happens when `DEBUG = False`.  Probably need to check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started running into this problem again, and returned to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-the-site-and-your-static-files-from-the-same-server):

> Configure your web server to serve the files in STATIC_ROOT under the
>   URL STATIC_URL. For example, here’s how to do this with Apache and
>   mod_wsgi.

With [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/), I changed my Caddyfile from this:

```
example.com {
    proxy / localhost:42069 {
        transparent
    }
}
```

to this:

```
example.com {
    root /path/to/project
    proxy / localhost:42069 {
        transparent
        except /static
    }
}
```

where 42069 is the port on which the project is listening.

[source](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/issues/695#issuecomment-201830568)

Answer (score 0):

That was it.  All I had to do was set [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT).

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/staticfiles/'
```

This should have been obvious, but I couldn't find anything when googling the problem.  Hopefully this helps others.